# Записать значения массива в value

Tags: php, html

Записать значения массива в value.

```
$mass_name = {array} [3]
  0 = {array} [2]
    name = "ryt"
    amount = "78"
  1 = {array} [2]
    name = "tyy"
    amount = "2"      
  2 = {array} [2]
    name = "tre"
    amount = "4"
```

Чтобы было так.

```
<div class="table-row">
  <input class="add-table-list" name="addName[]" type="text" value="ryt">
  <input class="add-table-list" name="addAmount[]" type="text" value="78">
  <label class="table-btn table-btn_delete"></label>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
  <input class="add-table-list" name="addName[]" type="text" value="ryy">
  <input class="add-table-list" name="addAmount[]" type="text" value="2">
  <label class="table-btn table-btn_delete"></label>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
  <input class="add-table-list" name="addName[]" type="text" value="tre">
  <input class="add-table-list" name="addAmount[]" type="text" value="4">
  <label class="table-btn table-btn_delete"></label>
</div>
```

Я пытаюсь сделать так

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($mass_name); $i++) { ?>
  <div class="table-row">
    <input class="add-table-list" name="addName[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $mass_name[$i]; ?>">
    <input class="add-table-list" name="addAmount[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $mass_name[$i]; ?>">
    <label class="table-btn table-btn_delete"></label>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Но выводит `array`. Как сделать чтобы выводил значения из массива?

Comment: Если вы работаете с массивом, то используйте не for, а foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как каждый элемент `$mass_name[$i]` это тоже массив, то добавьте нужный ключ:

```
<?php echo $mass_name[$i]['name']; ?>
<?php echo $mass_name[$i]['amount']; ?>
```

Comment: пробовал, выводит пустые поля

Comment: Ну а в `$mass_name` то есть хоть что-то?

Comment: Да, я сделал опечатку. Спасибо